# Visual Studio 2003 C#, struct compiling erro

Tags: c#, struct, compilation, visual-studio-2003

I have a problem with struct during compilation. I program in c# and use Visual Studio 2003.  [From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> When you create a struct object using the new operator, it gets created and the appropriate constructor is called. Unlike classes, structs can be instantiated without using the new operator. If you do not use new, the fields will remain unassigned and the object cannot be used until all of the fields are initialized.

You can instantiate a struct without new() statement; on my pc it works perfectly while on another pc I see compiling errors (new() required).
Is there some filter or flag on the Visual studio's environment (like TreatWarningsAsErrors) that can generate this behavior?

an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace myApp.Utils
{
    ....
    public struct StructParam
    {
        public int iIndex;
        public int[] iStartNoteArray;
        public int[] iFinalNoteArray;
        public int[] iDimension;
        public int[] iStartSequence;
        public ArrayList m_iRowIncValueArray;   
    };
    ....
}
--------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------
using System;
using System.Collections;
using myApp.Utils;

namespace myApp.Main
{
    ....
    public class frmMain : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        ....
        static void Main() 
        {
            ....
            StructParam oStructParam;
            oStructParam.iIndex = 0;
            oStructParam.iStartNoteArray = new int[]{0, 0};
            oStructParam.iFinalNoteArray = new int[]{0, 0};
            oStructParam.iDimension = new int[]{0, 0};
            oStructParam.iStartSequence = new int[]{0, 0};
            oStructParam.m_iRowIncValueArray = new ArrayList();

            ArrayList myArray = new ArrayList();
            myArray.Add(oStructParam);
            ....
        }
        .....
    }
    ....
}
```

I don't think the problem is in code but in some Visual Studio's environment variable.

Comment: Please give a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. Is there any reason you're using a version of Visual Studio which is 10 years old?

Comment: Hi, I must use Visual studio 2003 for backward compatibility (
unfortunately it is not my choice)...

Comment: So what's the exact error message, and on what line?

Comment: Hi, compiler error is "use of the local variable 'oStructParam' is not assigned." and the error is on 'myArray.Add(oStructParam);'. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm. Exact same version of the compiler in both cases?

Comment: On my pc 7.10.6001.4 on the other 7.10.3052.4

Comment: Perhaps it was a bug fixed in a service pack then? (Having said that, that looks like the version of msvcr71.dll. How did you obtain it?)

Comment: Hi, probably as you tell is a problem of service pack, the version is taken from csc.exe file, do you know if Microsoft has published a bug fixes list for the compiler? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you got that number from running `csc /version`? That's the number I'm interested in. (I'm confused by a number with 7.x as the VS2012 version returns 4.0.30319.17929 on my machine.)

Comment: Hello, just to see, what is the role of msvcr71.dll?

Comment: It's a runtime DLL. The version number you gave corresponds to a common version of that DLL.

Answer (score 3):

To use a struct without calling new, you must assign all its members first.

For example,

```
struct Point
{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public int DoSomething() { return x * y; }
}

Point p;
p.x = 1;
p.y = 2;
p.DoSomething();
```

Notice x and y here are fields, NOT properties. You must assign all fields before making use of the struct. If you were to include an auto-property, for example, where you didn't have access to the underlying field, then it would not be possible.

Comment: Assuming it's a local variable, of course. If it's an instance/static variable, it'll just get the default value.